# React Native PDF View "PDFView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF from URL in my react native project.

I created a open report file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PDFView from 'react-native-view-pdf';

class OpenBGReport extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <PDFView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onError={(error) => console.log('onError', error)}
        onLoad={() => console.log('PDF rendered from url')}
        resource="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"
        resourceType="url"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default OpenBGReport;
```

However, I'm getting the error: `Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "PDFView" was not found in the UIManager.`

I already tried to run npm link react-native-pdf-view but still same error.

How can I open a PDF from URL in React Native?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if the framework is linked properly in your project?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: From RN 0.60 there is no need to link - Native Modules are now Autolinked

Comment: Check the linking from the framework installation https://github.com/rumax/react-native-PDFView

Comment: I already tried react-native link and still same issue

Comment: Your RN version is 0.60 ?

Comment: I have: react-native-cli: 2.0.1. react-native: 0.59.8

Comment: You have to link manually. You can check this line in your pod file "pod 'RNPDF', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf'" is it available or not. If not then you will have to link manually.

Comment: What if I upgrade ro rn 0.60? How can I check pod file?

Comment: I have the file RNPDF.podspec

Comment: If you upgrade your rn version to 0.60 the it will auto link for IOS and Android both but if your version is lower, then you have to link manual

Comment: Thanks. How can I manually link? I have do it because I can't upgrade react native. react-native upgrade returns Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: You have to follow steps of it's manual installation for IOS and Android both.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you manually link for iOS:

`cd ios/ && pod deintegrate`

Then add the following to your `Podfile`:

```
pod 'RNPDF', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf'
```

Then run `pod install`.

This is how you manually link for Android:

1. Go to your `MainApplication.java` and add the following to the top of the file:

   `import com.rumax.reactnative.pdfviewer.PDFViewPackage;`

Then below it:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      packages.add(new PDFViewPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

2. In `android/settings.gradle`, add:

```
    include ':react-native-view-pdf'
    project(':react-native-view-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-view-pdf/android')
```

3. In `android/app/build.gradle`, add:

   `implementation project(':react-native-view-pdf')`

Please keep in mind you are only doing the above because you said you were on RN 0.59.8, you will not need to do this post-RN 60ish as everything is now autolinked.